# Web.config not accepting the currency symbols

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have added following line in my web.config in app settings section and published the build and ran the website on the server. But it throws error. 
Web config works fine in development environment. 
following screenshot shows both the line of code and error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X7b0.png)

Comment: Can you post the the one that is working "FINE" in development environment as well?

Comment: same line working fine in the development environment.

Comment: See the line in the attached image.